# How to call an interactive function while building helm-sources?

Tags: helm

With a region selected I can call this function "accdeb" (below) that gives me the right results in a list. How can I feed this list to helm ?

With the code below I get: wrong-number-of-arguments.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
(setq some-helm-source
      '((name . "stacktrace from region")
        (candidates . accdeb)
        (action . (lambda (candidate)
                    (message "%s" candidate)))))

(defun my-first-helm-command ()
  (interactive)
  (helm :sources '(some-helm-source)
        :buffer "*helm backtrace*"))

(defun accdeb (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (mapcar (lambda (arg)
            (shell-command-to-string
              (concat "/home/demetra/scripts/eaddrs2line.sh /my/workspace" 
                      " "
                      arg)))
          (split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end) "\n")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the arguments from `accdeb`:

```
(defun accdeb ()
  (with-helm-current-buffer
    (let ((beg (region-beginning))
          (end (region-end)))
      (mapcar (lambda (arg)
                (shell-command-to-string
                 (concat "/home/demetra/scripts/eaddrs2line.sh /my/workspace" 
                         " "
                         arg)))
              (split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end) "\n")))))
```

Comment: Does this say how to use an *interactive* function in this context?

Comment: I thought I would get one function that I can call interactively and also call that interactive function from helm-source. Maybe that isn't possible. This one works too.   Thanks.